# Understanding the Array.filter() method with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6

I am writing a comparison function that check is all twenty six letters of the alphabet exist inside of a string input.

```
let temp = (str) => { 
  let myString = str.replace(' ', '').split('')
    .filter((item,i,arr) => arr.indexOf(item) === i).join('');

  return myString.length === 26 ? true : false;
}

temp('hello'); //false
temp('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'); //true
```

This works. But I am having trouble understanding what is exactly happening during the `filter()` method. To me, it looks like it is just checking "If index of item being passed in = index" and its hard to visualize. Anyone care to help me understand what is actually happening? Thanks!

Also, is there a better way to write this function? Thanks!

Comment: It is filtering out duplicates.

Comment: `indexOf()` returns the index of the *first* match, `i` is the current index. They're not the same when the current character is a duplicate.